# How do you enable document function in XSLT (called from ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I have a stylesheet using a for each loop over the XML doc but when it comes accross using the `document()` method it fails.

```
<td >
    <xsl:value-of select="document('Departments.xml')/Departments/Department[@Id=dep]/Name"/>
</td>
```

The variable has a value each loop which prints out

> Execution of the "document()" function was prohibited. Use the
> "XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction" property to enable it.

Comment: Well, you do exactly what it says. Perhaps if you show us how you are invoking the transformation, we will be able to tell you how to add the relevant settings.

Comment: @MichaelKay my aspx file calls it via                 <asp:Xml ID="XML" runat="server" DocumentSource="~/data/xml/People.xml" TransformSource="~/data/xml/People.xslt"></asp:Xml> that hsd a for-each loop, it is getting the var 
          <xsl:variable name="dep" select="Department"/>

Comment: I am not sure the ASP.NET `asp:Xml` control allows you to configure the XsltSettings, you might need to implement your own calling `XslCompiledTransform` with the right settings.

Comment: I thought that `asp:Xml` uses `XslTransform` where you don't have the `XsltSettings` problem. Which version of .NET, which kind of environment is that where you use `asp:xml` but run into that error related to `XsltSettings` which are rather specific to `XslCompiledTransform`?

Comment: i've set 
            // Create the XsltSettings object with script enabled.
            XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(false, true);

            settings.EnableDocumentFunction = true; but no luck in cs file. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.10.0
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.10.0+31321.278
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA241
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019
blies and MSBuild support. the code that transforms xml to xslt file is index.aspx

Comment: It seems the `asp:xml` control indeed internally https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/WebControls/xml.cs#L586 uses a mixture of `XslCompiledTransform` and `XslTransform`, I am not sure in which cases which ones of the two of them is used but I see no easy way there to ensure you can provide `XsltSettings` if `XslCompiledTransform` is used. So in the end it might be better to not use the `asp:xml` control but set up your own code running `XslCompiledTransform` with the `XsltSettings` you need to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I think if `XslCompiledTransform` is used by the `asp:xml` control instead of `XslTransform` it means that the environment you are working in has set `aspnet:RestrictXmlControls` to true (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh975440(v=vs.120))

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:RestrictXmlControls" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

so you might need to try/check whether your locale web.config can set it back to

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:RestrictXmlControls" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

to have `XslTransform` being used where you are not restricted by default XsltSettings.